# Is this correct about ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Could you confirm I understand [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) correctly.

> However, always use POST requests
>   when:
>
> ```
> - A cached file is not an option (update a file or database on the
> ```
>
> server)

Using POST, the file specified in `xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);`
will not be cached (sent to `\Temporary Internet Files`) ? It will stay on the server only?

If this is true, is the updated html file after calling ajax POST, being updated in the `\Temporary Internet Files` ?

Am I missing any other important information of this mechanism?

Thank You.

Comment: It's best to quote the page and not link to it. If the linked to page goes down the question becomes incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct assumption if you use `POST`, you have GET in your call.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
```