# How do I ensure jQuery ajax call does not send a local copy of file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',      
  url: "string.txt",
  cache: false,
  success: function(str){
    alert("Data is: "+ str);
  }
});
```

In this example, string.txt is sent to the cache (\Temporary Internet Files)
How do I ensure that the file is **not** sent. I do not want copy to be sent.
Only a read from the server. [Am I missing an option?](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I set cache to false but that does not block it from being sent to client. 
For example, [ajax POST](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) does not send a local copy.....

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784340/is-this-correct-about-ajax-post) is some background info to what i am trying to do, but with jQuery.

I am curious as to why the standard [ajax post](http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) seems to have the desired functionality I am looking for and am unable to do that with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: I have to admit I'm not sure exactly what your asking...

Comment: Don't conclude that just because the file exists in your Temporary Internet Files directory that it's not being pulled from the server each time your AJAX request runs.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts: Sorry about that. I want the file to stay in the server sides directory only. No local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or set a no cache header server-side.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: Can I do that just for this specific file?

Comment: @Tommy: Of course.  HTTP cache-control headers are part of each individual respomse, not some global server-wide setting.

Comment: @Wyzard: thanks, obviously, I do not know much about server side functionality. I am curious as to why the standard ajax post http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp seems to have the desired functionality I am looking for and am unable to do that with jQuery?

Comment: I set general the HTTP header "Cache-Control", "max-age=0" in all server responses. It say client that the client must every time verify your client side cache. If server set also "ETag" in the HTTP header with a value like a hash from data in the responses, then the "ETag" from the client side cache will be always automatically send to server. Server can verify clients "ETag" with the current server data and answer with response contains empty body and "304 Not Modified" instead of "200 OK" in response. Then $.ajax response will be get data from the local client cache.